# Pixel resolution phototransistor array

Tags: phototransistor

I would like to ask if anybody knows some technology which is like array of phototransistor with accuracy in **mm** . Like some display on which I put someting and get by wire data of pixel which are shadowed, just only logic state ( 0 = Nothin/Ligh, 1 = Someting is put down on screen/Dark).

```
000
010
000
```

[image]

My first idea was solve it by many phototranzistor in matrix, but it haven't that
necessary accuracy which I would need. ( I think even SMD phototranzistor for this are so "big").

***Thanks everyone for some help, and I'am sorry for my poor English. I hope you have get it what I've been wrote there.***

Comment: I user_somenumber, welcome to EEsx. If I understand your question, you are searching for a component that can read if light is hitting it or not, with the precision of 1mm, arranged in a matrix. If this is right please add some informations about your project and your thoughts up to now: on this board questions like "where to buy this product" are not allowed, and your question is borderline.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! If I understand correctly, you're looking to buy this component, not to make it yourself? That makes this question off topic following the guidelines ([help:on-topic]). I'm voting to put this question on hold until this is clarified. But besides that, isn't what you're looking for a simple low-resolution B/W camera? It depends with what kind of chip (and other factors, like power consumption) you want to read the data if that's a possibility, of course. So also this would be good to mention in your question! Thank you :)

Comment: An array of light sensing devices? Sounds like a camera.

Comment: @Camil: Since he's asking about the technology and how to do it and not for where to buy it, I don't get that it's off topic at all.

Comment: @OP: How many pixels do you need and what kind of accuracy are you looking for?

Comment: @EMFields I think 'technology' is misused here. The drawing, the use of 'some display' and the idea of getting information over wire, suggest a full component.

Comment: @Camil: The drawing gives an inkling of the pixel pattern he's talking about, he's using "like some display" to describe what he's trying to do - not what he's trying to buy - and I don't understand what you have against "by wire".  How else would you suggest he obtain the data he needs?

Comment: @EMFields I don't have anything against it, but 'by wire' suggests that data is read over some kind of data bus, I2C or SPI or the like, which suggests that some kind of processing is done.

Comment: @Camil: The OP obviously isn't expert in the use of English, yet he made what he's trying to do clear enough, so why would you vote to shut him down when there's clearly ambiguity in your perception of his intent when there's absolutely no help in that course of action?

Comment: @EMFields I'm voting to put the question _on hold_ until certain _uncertainties_ have been eliminated. The help is that after editing and reopening, we can efficiently discuss and actually help the OP. Also have a look at the two answers given up to now. If these are the answers the OP was looking for, the question is clearly to be put on hold. Now, if you want to discuss this further, let's use the chat and not the comments. But tell me before, because I'm not there right now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an optical mouse sensor, basically a low resolution B&W camera. The Agilent ADNS-3040 is one such sensor. You might need some optics for your application.

Comment: That's a clever approach. You can even read out the 22x22 pixel array "for diagnostic purposes" which makes it a lot easier to test alternative optics if you use it for applications other than as the guts of a mouse.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use a 2D CMOS sensor.

These are arrays of very small micro-meter size light detecting elements. They are easily found like 640x480 arrays. The complete sensing size of the chip would be some mm^2.

And, because it seems very important to you, the relative positioning of the sensing element on the array is almost perfect. (tolerances in the micro-meter range, maybe better)

If you don't need that resolution, just bin the pixel. That would decrease the noise and reduce the amount of provided data.

Unfortunately, you didn't specify what the application is. This solution requires that you plug your sensor into a MCU (which may require to be a fast one) or any kind of digital system such as CPLD, FPGA etc...